# Wondering if my computer books from 2002/2003 are still useful?

Tags: php, books, javascript

I found two books in my basement today and it was about Javascript and PHP/MySQL. Are they still useful? I hope it's still useful, since I don't want to buy a new one...

1.[JavaScript - Comprehensive, Second Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0619063343)

2.[PHP and MySQL for Dynamic Web Sites: Visual QuickPro Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321186486)

Comment: Those technologies have changed significantly over the last 8-9 years, but I haven't read them so I can't say for sure. If you read them in the first place, and have kept using JS/PHP/MySQL since, then there's no need to worry. If you haven't touched them since those books... I'd say that you might want to start fresh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some books don't age and are still useful [28 years later](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201000237). But I'm afraid that particularly with these two, it's not the case. Especially with the PHP/MySQL one. It'd be totally obsolete knowledge. In case of Javascript one -- it could serve you to get to know the basics, the language itself didn't change that much. But it doesn't cover topics,  which today are basic knowledge of Javascript, like AJAX or frameworks.